# SQLite how to store a byte array in a single table cell

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, byte

I'm using SQLite database to store my Android data. 
How can i store a byte array byte[] in a single cell.
Because there are only types as int or strings.

I heard something about BLOB, maybe you can explain it to me?

Another option is to convert the byte array to a string and convert it back when using it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte arrays are directly supported, like the other types, by the [ContentValues.put()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20byte[]%29) and [Cursor.getBlob()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#getBlob%28int%29) functions.

Comment: But BLOB is suitable only for large byte arrays, right? What about, say, 8 or 16 bytes, that need to be inserted and fetched quickly.

Comment: @Ixx There is no lower limit on the size of a byte array. And what else would you use?